# MongoDB: Get all nearby with filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In MongoDB, I have models of `User`, `Token`, and `Boost`.

A user can have one or more tokens and one or more boosts.

`Token` has a `2dsphere` location field.

And `Boost` has `startTime` and `stopTime` Date fields.

A user is said to have an active boost if `Date.now()` is greater than `boost.startTime()` and less than `boost.stopTime()`.

What Mongo aggregation can I write to fetch me all the tokens near a particular location that belong to users with at least one active boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I have created a mock data

```
token collection:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b97541c6af22cc65216ffd8"),
    "userid" : "5b9753726af22cc65216ffd6",
    "location" : {
        "longitude" : 80.250875,
        "latitude" : 13.052519
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b97543a6af22cc65216ffd9"),
    "userid" : "5b97537e6af22cc65216ffd7",
    "location" : {
        "longitude" : 80.249995,
        "latitude" : 13.051819
    }
}

boost collection :
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b9754796af22cc65216ffda"),
        "startTime" : ISODate("2018-09-11T05:36:57.149Z"),
        "stopTime" : ISODate("2018-09-11T05:36:57.149Z"),
        "userid" : "5b9753726af22cc65216ffd6"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b9754b46af22cc65216ffdb"),
        "startTime" : ISODate("2018-10-08T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "stopTime" : ISODate("2018-10-08T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "userid" : "5b97537e6af22cc65216ffd7"
    }

Users collection :
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b9753726af22cc65216ffd6"),
            "userName" : "user111"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b97537e6af22cc65216ffd7"),
            "userName" : "user222"
        }
```

The aggregate query to fetch all the tokens near a particular location that belong to users with at least one active boost is:

```
 db.token.aggregate([
{
     "$geoNear": {
        "near": { type: "Point", coordinates: [80.248797,13.050599] },
        "distanceField": "location",
        "maxDistance": 1000,
        "includeLocs": "location",
        "spherical": true
     }
   },
   {"$lookup" : {"from":"boost",
                 "localField" : "userid",
                "foreignField" : "userid",
                 "as" : "boostDocs"
      }},
   {"$unwind" : "$boostDocs"},
   {"$match" : {"$and":[{"boostDocs.startTime":{"$lte":new Date("11/09/2018")}},{"boostDocs.stopTime":{"$gte":new Date("10/09/2018")}}]}}
   ])
```

**Notice that query to match the location is at the top of the query as $geoNear will only work if its the first stage of the aggregation pipeline.** 
**The Date that I've used for comparison is just to check if my query works. You can specify your date or Date.now() as per your requirement.**

Comment: A M A Z I N G. Works perfectly.  Could you explain a bit how it works? I get the location matching part well but I don't quite understand how the lookup/unwind/match parts work...

Comment: thanks for the upvote and comment! After matching nearby location from the token collection, the next stage is lookup (left outer join) from boosts collection based on userid. So the matching document from boosts collection will be returned as an array..The $unwind operator will return a document for each element in the boostDocs array. Finally using a match stage to match the dates in boostDocs. To understand better, please run the query stage by stage like geonear first and then geonear and lookup...let me know if you need any other help.